# Как установить app:layout_rowWeight и app:layout_columnWeight программно

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня есть кнопка в макете:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="1"
    android:tag="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
```

Теперь я хочу создать данную кнопку программно. Но я не знаю как установить параметры: `layout_columnWeight` и`layout_rowWeight`

Я попытался сделать что-то похожее.:

```
button.setLayoutRowWeight(1);
button.setLayoutColumnWeight(1);
```

Но это неправильный код.

Это мой код:

```
GridLayout numsTable = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.numsTable);

String[] btn_name = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < btn_name.length; i++) {
        numButton = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.numButtons), null, 0);
        numButton.setId(i);
        numButton.setText(btn_name[i]);
        numButton.setTag(i);
        numsTable.addView(numButton);
    }
```

Я хочу получить что-то подобное:

```
GridLayout numsTable = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.numsTable);

String[] btn_name = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < btn_name.length; i++) {
        numButton = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.numButtons), null, 0);
        numButton.setId(i);
        numButton.setText(btn_name[i]);
        numButton.setLayoutRowWeight(1);
        numButton.setLayoutColumnWeight(1);
        numButton.setTag(i);
        numsTable.addView(numButton);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть класс `GridLayout.LayoutParams`, у которого есть поля `columnSpec` и `rowSpec`. В этих полях лежат объекты класса `GridLayout.Spec`, в которых задаются нужные вам параметры. То есть вам нужно создать объекты Spec с нужными вам параметрами и передать их в конструктор

```
LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpec, columnSpec)
```